# Can we ping to PC which connect sharing Wi-Fi from other PC in network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, lan

This is my network diagram:
[image: diagram]

Can I ping from PC2 (window) to PC1(window)?

Comment: not enough info. Short answer: if your mac is doing nat you cant, if its bridging, it depends on your mac and windows firewall

Comment: @DGoiko do you have any experiment in Bridge mode when sharing internet by MAC. I think it using NAT automatically

Comment: Hello. I've zero expertise with mac, however, in linux (which is the background of mac after all) bridge mode means no NAT, so the network card is connected to a virtual SWITCH where the virtual PC is located. The best shot for you would be to retrieve all three PCs IPs and check if they're in the same network. If they're, you'll most likely to be able to ping pc1.